# Multiple Databases - Database Migration Plugin with Grails 2

Tags: grails, database-migration

I have been working with grails database migration plugin for long time but I always used only one database.  I have been looking for an example or at least to know if it is possible to do it with multiple databases, I have more than 8 databases and changing all of them manually is quite complicated.

thank you in advance for your help

Gil

Comment: Are these 8 instances of the same schema, or 8 different schemas?

Answer (score 1):

So, as there was no answer to my question, I will answer it myself. After receiving a message from Burt Beckwith he told me this was not currently possible but he will do his best to add this feature.

***UPDATE January 8th 2013****

The new version of db migration plugin covers multiple datasources now:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/pull/11

How to do it:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.reports.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.reports.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog-reports.groovy']
```